# Edx Developer Stack not showing anything after hitting to local host. Css for the page is not coming in lms

Tags: devstack, edx

I have a strange problem in edx devstack. When I am running devstack after paver command on my localhost then I am not able to get anything on the screen once the browser screen come to loading state.

Then after a lot of time nothing is being displayed on the screen and I can see some warnings in the logs which I have attached with this que. 
I have commented that code which are causing the warning message. 
But after commenting warnings have gone but nothing has changed the browser again goes in loading mode and nothing happens on the screen after hitting to localhost URL,it just go in to the loading mode and nothing is being displayed.

I have also tried to run the openedx in firefox but in fore fox the links and everythings are coming but they are coming with out any style and design for the edx. I have attached a screenshot for the same.

[image]

Please help me with this issue as I am not able to figure out what to do.
P.S. I have re-installed the whole stack using virtual box, but nothing has worked for me.

Thank you very much in advance.

```html
Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2015-03-29 05:16:58,318 WARNING 2092 [edxmako.shortcuts] shortcuts.py:56 - Cannot find corresponding link for name: JOBS
2015-03-29 05:16:58,319 WARNING 2092 [edxmako.shortcuts] shortcuts.py:56 - Cannot find corresponding link for name: JOBS
2015-03-29 05:16:58,321 WARNING 2092 [edxmako.shortcuts] shortcuts.py:56 - Cannot find corresponding link for name: NEWS
2015-03-29 05:16:58,323 WARNING 2092 [edxmako.shortcuts] shortcuts.py:56 - Cannot find corresponding link for name: NEWS
2015-03-29 05:16:59,991 INFO 2092 [django_comment_client.utils] utils.py:344 - 3 queries run, total 0.003 seconds
[29/Mar/2015 05:16:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30740
2015-03-29 05:17:11,453 INFO 2092 [django_comment_client.utils] utils.py:344 - 1 queries run, total 0.001 seconds
[29/Mar/2015 05:17:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30700
2015-03-29 05:17:11,458 INFO 2092 [django_comment_client.utils] utils.py:344 - 1 queries run, total 0.0 seconds
[29/Mar/2015 05:17:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30700
[29/Mar/2015 05:18:31] "GET /static/css/vendor/font-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 200 28835
[29/Mar/2015 05:18:31] "GET /static/css/vendor/jquery.qtip.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1677
2015-03-29 05:18:31,573 INFO 2092 [django_comment_client.utils] utils.py:344 - 1 queries run, total 0.0 seconds
CONTINUE....
```

Comment: Stack Overflow won't be a good way to get help with Open edX.  Have you tried the mailing list?  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/edx-code

Comment: all right. I have asked this que to the group link that you gave me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Guys after I posted on google group I finally got the answer. I feel like I should post this answer on stackoverflow so it is convenient for people who got stuck in their development.

1) From the screen shot it seems it is a permission issue. Give correct permission for edx-platform and themes folder if you are using any. Then try restarting the LMS and CMS and reload the page.

**sudo chown -R edxapp:edxapp /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform
sudo chown -R edxapp:edxapp /edx/app/edxapp/themes.
sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl restart edxapp:**

2) If you are able to load CMS page and LMS showing blank, may be mongodb is not running.
    **#mongo , if it shows some error check if swap size is full
    # free -m**

If swap is full, create new swap file, follow the instruction in the below link blindly.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/

Then try restarting mongodb, you can try restarting the system once.